# Calculate mean of specific row pattern

Tags: r, dataframe, row, sequence, mean

I have a dataframe like this:

```
V1 = paste0("AB", seq(1:48))
V2 = seq(1:48)

test = data.frame(name = V1, value = V2)
```

I want to calculate the means of the value-column and specific rows.

The pattern of the rows is pretty complicated:

```
Rows of MeanA1: 1, 5, 9
Rows of MeanA2: 2, 6, 10
Rows of MeanA3: 3, 7, 11
Rows of MeanA4: 4, 8, 12

Rows of MeanB1: 13, 17, 21
Rows of MeanB2: 14, 18, 22
Rows of MeanB3: 15, 19, 23
Rows of MeanB4: 16, 20, 24

Rows of MeanC1: 25, 29, 33
Rows of MeanC2: 26, 30, 34
Rows of MeanC3: 27, 31, 35
Rows of MeanC4: 28, 32, 36

Rows of MeanD1: 37, 41, 45
Rows of MeanD2: 38, 42, 46
Rows of MeanD3: 39, 43, 47
Rows of MeanD4: 40, 44, 48
```

As you see its starting at 4 different points (1, 13, 25, 37) then always +4 and for the following 4 means its just stepping 1 more row down.

I would like to have an output of all these means in one list.

Any ideas? NOTE: In this example the mean is of course always the middle number, but my real df is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure about the output format you require, but the following codes can calculate what you want anyhow.

```
calc_mean1 <- function(x) mean(test$value[seq(x, by = 4, length.out = 3)])
calc_mean2 <- function(x){sapply(x:(x+3), calc_mean1)}
output <- lapply(seq(1, 37, 12), calc_mean2)
names(output) <- paste0('Mean', LETTERS[seq_along(output)]) # remove this line if more than 26 groups.
output

## $MeanA
## [1] 5 6 7 8

## $MeanB
## [1] 17 18 19 20

## $MeanC
## [1] 29 30 31 32

## $MeanD
## [1] 41 42 43 44
```

Comment: This is a bit overfitted to the question. For example if OP has more than 26 groups, you will run out of `LETTERS`...

Comment: @Sotos you are right. The question gives an example with 'MeanA1', 'MeanD1',..., which does not mention what to do when more than 26 groups, or the fourth line of the codes could simply be removed.

Comment: Commenting as you did next to the function is probably the best option.

Answer (score 2):

An idea via base R is to create a grouping variable for every 4 rows, split the data every 12 rows (`nrow(test) / 4`) and aggregate to find the mean, i.e.

```
test$new = rep(1:4, nrow(test)%/%4)
lapply(split(test, rep(1:4, each = nrow(test) %/% 4)), function(i)
                                              aggregate(value ~ new, i, mean))

#    $`1`
#      new value
#    1   1     5
#    2   2     6
#    3   3     7
#    4   4     8

#    $`2`
#      new value
#    1   1    17
#    2   2    18
#    3   3    19
#    4   4    20

#    $`3`
#      new value
#    1   1    29
#    2   2    30
#    3   3    31
#    4   4    32

#    $`4`
#      new value
#    1   1    41
#    2   2    42
#    3   3    43
#    4   4    44
```

Answer (score 1):

And yet another way.

```
fun <- function(DF, col, step = 4){
  run <- nrow(DF)/step^2
  res <- lapply(seq_len(step), function(inc){
    inx <- seq_len(run*step) + (inc - 1)*run*step
    dftmp <- DF[inx, ]
    tapply(dftmp[[col]], rep(seq_len(step), run), mean, na.rm = TRUE)
  })
  names(res) <- sprintf("Mean%s", LETTERS[seq_len(step)])
  res
}

fun(test, 2, 4)
#$MeanA
#1 2 3 4 
#5 6 7 8 
#
#$MeanB
# 1  2  3  4 
#17 18 19 20 
#
#$MeanC
# 1  2  3  4 
#29 30 31 32 
#
#$MeanD
# 1  2  3  4 
#41 42 43 44
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Another great solution!

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you wanted a long list of the means, I assumed it could also be a vector where you just have all these values. You would get that like this:

```
V1 = paste0("AB", seq(1:48))
V2 = seq(1:48)

test = data.frame(name = V1, value = V2)
meanVector <- NULL

for (i in 1:(nrow(test)-8)) {
  x <- c(test$value[i], test$value[i+4], test$value[i+8])
  m <- mean(x)
  meanVector <- c(meanVector, m)
}
```